# Mapstruct: Access "this" in custom mapper method

Tags: java, mapstruct

Given following method, which maps a `FarmInputDto` to a `Farm`:

```
@Mapping(target = "assignment", source = "user", qualifiedByName = "addUserToAssignments")
public abstract Farm toFarm(FarmInputDto input, User user);
```

Is it possible to access the just created instance of `Farm` inside the custom mapper method?

```
protected UserFarmAssignment addUserToAssignments(User user) {
    return new UserFarmAssignment(user, "$FARM_INSTANCE?");
}
```

I've read about [@MappingTarget](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances), but this does not work (probably it is not meant to be used like that in this context anyway):

```
protected List<UserFarmAssignment> addUserToAssignments(User user, @MappingTarget Farm farm) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `@ObjectFactory`.. See [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#object-factories) for more info.